# How to use an Upgraded Version of the Hibernate Validator Jar in Wildfly 8.2?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, hibernate-validator

I'm in the process of integrating Hibernate Validator into our Java based web app. We use JSR-310 types extensively.

I see that Hibernate Validator version **5.2** adds support for these types, so I've added version `5.2.0.Beta1` to my EAR deployment's `/lib` directory like all of our other dependencies.

But when I test our deployed EAR, I get the following error:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.time.Instant.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:723) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:601) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:412) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
```

Notice that **hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final** appears in the stack trace not the **5.2.0.Beta1** that I have in my EAR file.

I think what's happening is that Wildfly (we're using 8.2.0.Final) is including an older version of the hibernate-validator JARs instead of the newer ones that we're including in our EAR file. How do I prevent this from happening?

I think the answer might be to include a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file that coaxes Wildfly to use the JAR that I supply. I've found this [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), but it's not clear what to include in that file to coax Wildfly into using the JAR I supply.

Answer (score 2):

Using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` might be one way of doing this. However, I would suggest to just update the module configurations under `modules/system/layers/base`. Copy `hibernate-validator-5.2.0.Beta1.jar` and `hibernate-validator-cdi-5.2.0.Beta1.jar` into `org/hibernate/validator/main` resp. `org/hibernate/validator/cdi/main` and update the respective `modules.xml` to point to the new jar files.